# Let $r, \theta$ be the polar coordinates on the plane. Let $f(x,y)\in C^2$. Find $\frac {\partial^2f}{\partial r\partial \theta}$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

$\mathbf {Question}$

Let $r, \theta$ be the polar coordinates on the plane. Let $f(x,y)\in C^2$. Find $\frac {\partial^2f}{\partial r\partial \theta}$ and $\frac {\partial 2f}{\partial r^2}$ and express them as linear combination of the first and second partials of $f$ with respect to x and y.

$\mathbf {Attempt}$

I thought this would be $\frac {\partial f}{\partial \theta}=\frac {\partial f}{\partial x}\frac {\partial x }{\partial \theta}+\frac {\partial f}{\partial y}\frac {\partial y}{\partial \theta}$.

Doing an analogous method for the second derivatives, but I'm not sure of this, could someone explain in detail what I have to do, and why? (This also doesn't fulfill the "express as linear combinations" task either...)

Comment: It sounds like you are on the right track, just take the derivatives of $f(r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta)$. Did you get stuck somewhere?

Comment: Yes, I need to get rid of the $\frac {\partial \theta}{\partial x}$ to satisfy the condition asked, but I don't know how to do this...

Comment: You need also to use explicit expressions for $x(r,\theta)$ and $y(r,\theta)$. You get them by definition of polar coordinates.

Comment: Think of $\frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}$ and $\frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}$ as coefficients in the linear combination.

Comment: @David I thought I was supposed to do that, but those partials are not constants, they are functions, doesn't that mean I have to do something else?

Comment: @A.G. Am I okay to think $x_\theta=-r\sin \theta?, x_r=\cos \theta$?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCDYes, you should do something like [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/957434/express-partial-derivatives-of-second-order-and-the-laplacian-in-polar-coordin?rq=1) or [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1100845/express-frac-partial2z-partial-r2-in-terms-of-r-theta-and-the?rq=1)

Comment: At any given $(r,\theta)$, $\frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}$ and  $\frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}$ are held constant as the partials of the function $f$ vary.